# Cassandra and Hector issue

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, hector

I had setup Cassandra on 1 node and flooded it with data. Then I configured a second node, its initial token, seed etc. and started Cassandra on it.
Now when I ran my Hector code on 1 node cluster it gave me all the data. But when I am running the same code on 2 node cluster I get less data(lesser number of columns and rows) . I am not understanding what I am doing wrong.
I even tried to add a string of hosts using CassandraHostConfigurator but still I am not getting the entire data. 
I also tried running nodetool repair but still facing the same issue

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding nodes into the cluster you should start that node with 
**`auto_bootstrap: true`** in **cassandra.yaml** so that the other nodes in the cluster (in your case the only node) will stream the data new node (according to token).

**Edit** For the Casssandra-1.0 onwards there is no option as bootstrap in this case we have to start second node with new token calculated it will start streaming data.once streaming is finished run `nodetool move <new_token>`. for more information see [Adding nodes to cluster](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/operations/cluster_management)

If this is not done the second node will not have the data which it is supposed to hold according to token. And when you try to read data out of Cassandra It may be looking for the data on newly added node according to token but as there is no data you are not getting correct result.

Comment: But there is no option of auto_bootstrap in Cassandra 1.1.0 . So where do I specify this option?

Answer (score 0):

- Please check all your firewall, iptables config is accept node communicate to another

after you add a node to ring , Use `nodetool ring` to view data load example my cluster have 3 nodes result will be similar:

> 192.168.23.84   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  37.52 GB        33.33%
>   192.168.23.85     datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  37.5 GB         33.33%
>   192.168.23.86   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  37.5 GB        33.33%

if it similar that, when u use hector, use this code to check hector request to which server:

```
MutationResult result = mutator.execute();
logger.info(" host:" + result.getHostUsed().getHost());
```

try to write many time to recheck the destination host is contain all your host.

i use this CassandraHostConfigurator to add many host to a cluster when use Hector 
example:

```
CassandraHostConfigurator cassandraHostConfigurator = new CassandraHostConfigurator(
                "192.168.23.84:9160,192.168.23.85:9160,192.168.23.86:9160");
cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("testcluster", cassandraHostConfigurator);
```